# How to return a pointer of a function and using as a parameter?

Tags: c++, linked-list

I don't know if the question can express my problem correctly, hope the explantion and the code help. English is not my first language, so be patient. And it's a homework, so I can't use library stl related stuff. 
How to traverse correctly a linked list without the while/for loop, and returning the current pointer and give the same pointer to 
a function? (Maybe mutual recursion? I am just saying, maybe my idea is wrong).

Let's pretend that something keeps happening (it's an external variable that gives me true) during the execution of the program.
How can I keep traversing the same list, without always starting from the head?

From the beginning of the execution of the program, it has to start from the head, obviously, but then I should be able to "return" 
the next pointer, and then next.

Let's pretend we have the list of numbers (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7); 
The program starts and I return the pointer that points to 1, and that's fine, duringe the same the execution of the program, something happens
and I need to be returned 2, again, something happens again, then the function should return 3 etc.
How can I do that? 
The code you're seeing, is an idea, of what i would like to do. I am not sure, if what I would like to do is doable, and if it's not, what can i do?

```
struct node {
  int val;
  node* next;
};
class random {
 public:
  node* head = NULL;
  node* create() {
    node* tmp;
    for (int i = 1; i < 8; i = i + 1) {
      tmp = new node;
      tmp->val = i;
      tmp->next = head;
      head = tmp;
    }
    return this->head;
  }
  bool SomethingHappens() {
    if  // somethingHappens
      return true;
  }
  node* RightPointer(node* current) {
    bool somethinghappened;
    somethinghappened = SomethingHappens();
    if (somethinghappened) {
      current = current->next;
    }
    return current;
  }
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  random list;
  list.RightPointer(list.head);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code won't compile. You're missing semicolons.

Comment: I know there are syntax errors in the code(it's not even a code, it's just some lines, to give some idea of what I would like to do). I am not asking for that, I am asking about a concept/logic help, if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
node* ptr = list.head;
while ((ptr = list.RightPointer(ptr)) != nullptr)
{
    // Do something with the pointer
}
```

We start by calling `RightPointer` with `list.head` (because of the initialization of `ptr`). Each call to `RightPointer` will either return the same node (if nothing happened) or the `next` pointer (if something happened).

When you reach the list end the function will return a null pointer which makes the loop condition false and stops the iteration.

---

To make the code possibly easier to read for a beginner, the above loop is equivalent to this:

```
// Get the first node back from RightPointer
node* ptr = list.RightPointer(list.head);

// Loop while the pointer returned by RightPointer isn't a null pointer
while (ptr != nullptr)
{
    // Do something with the pointer...
    // ...
    // ...
    // ...

    // Get the (possibly) next pointer from RightPointer
    ptr = list.RightPointer(ptr);

    // Note that the above call could return the same node that was passed to it
    // Or it might return ptr->next
    // This means the above assignment could either be equivalent to
    //     ptr = ptr;
    // or
    //     ptr = ptr->next;
}
```

Comment: does the while loop breaks when somethinghappens and does return the pointer where it started? for example, there is the list of 1,2,3,4.5,6, 7 Something happened and now the pointer is pointing to 4, does then trasversing starting from 4 or it starts from one again? What i would like to do, is that if something happens, and the pointer is pointing to 4, then when the function is called again, during the execution of the program, the pointer starts from 4 and not from 1. hope i have been clear

Comment: @user12095096 The loop will always continue with whatever node the `RightPointer` returned.

Comment: And what if I would like to give that pointer returned to the function?

Comment: @user12095096 Do you mean you want to pass it to the next call to the `RightPointer` function? That's what this loop does as well. Have you *tried* this? Have you tried to *debug* this in any way ([rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or stepping through the code in an actual debugger)?